# Stock widget in Apex Launcher

Tags: app-widgets, apex-launcher-pro

How do I get to use stock widgets (like email) on HTC Sensation 4G running on ICS and Sense 3.6 with Apex Launcher Pro?

Comment: Long press an empty area of your homescreen and choose widgets. Doesn't that work? You need enough space to be able to place the widget, though.

Answer (score 2):

These widgets are **not standard** widgets. They use non-standard APIs of the Sense launcher and thus that other launcher's don't have and thus, they can't use them.

This is why, you can't use Sense widgets with custom launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Most widgets can be added by going to the Widgets section in the App Drawer and long pressing them, then selecting an empty area of the homescreen to place it. You will see all standard widgets there, except for the HTC ones. Those widgets are made specifically for and locked to the HTC Sense launcher, unfortunately.

Comment: FYI long-pressing doesn't work in Android 4.x. You need to select the Widget out of the app drawer.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I'm using Apex Launcher and forgot that was not standard of the stock launcher. Edited the post, thanks.